# Media Player Not working on Samsung S3

Tags: android, media-player, samsung-mobile, android-mediarecorder

I have an application that works perfectly on my Nexus 4 however when I tried getting it to work on an S3 for testing it didn't work, the media player seemed to be glitching out

*Here is the code for the button that starts the media player*

```
play_sound_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play_sound_1);
        play_sound_1.animate().setDuration(dur);
        play_sound_1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {

                if (arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    try {
                        playSound1();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    play_sound_1.animate().setInterpolator(sDecelerator)
                            .scaleX(.85f).scaleY(.85f);
                } else if (arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    play_sound_1.animate().setInterpolator(sOvershooter)
                            .scaleX(1f).scaleY(1f);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });


public void playSound1() throws Exception{
    //Play sound
    PlaybackHandler.playRecording1(SOUND_ONE);
}
```

*PlayBack Handler class code:*

```
static void playRecording1(String output) throws Exception{
        ditchMediaPlayer1();
        mediaPlayer1 = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer1.setDataSource(output);
        mediaPlayer1.prepare();
        mediaPlayer1.start();
    }

private static void ditchMediaPlayer1() {
        if(mediaPlayer1 != null){
            try{
                mediaPlayer1.release();
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }       
    }
```

*Just in case here is the code for how I'm recording the audio files, just in-case the problem might be here:*

```
rec_sound_1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.rec_sound_1);
        rec_sound_1.animate().setDuration(dur);
        rec_sound_1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {

                if (arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    //begin recording
                    try {
                        RecordingHandler.beginRecording1(SOUND_ONE);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    rec_sound_1.animate().setInterpolator(sDecelerator)
                            .scaleX(.85f).scaleY(.85f);
                } else if (arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    rec_sound_1.animate().setInterpolator(sOvershooter)
                            .scaleX(1f).scaleY(1f);
                    //stop recording
                    RecordingHandler.stopRecording1();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

*RecordingHandler class*

```
static void beginRecording1(String output) throws Exception {

        ditchMediaRecorder1();
        File outFile = new File(output);        
        if(outFile.exists())
            outFile.delete();       
        recorder1 = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder1.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder1.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        recorder1.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_WB);
        recorder1.setAudioEncodingBitRate(16);
        recorder1.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
        recorder1.setOutputFile(output);
        recorder1.prepare();
        recorder1.start(); 
    }
    private static void ditchMediaRecorder1() {
        //if we have the recorder, release it
        if(recorder1 != null)
            recorder1.release(); }  
    static void stopRecording1() {
        if(recorder1 != null)
            recorder1.stop(); }
```

---

---

TLDR; Here is the stack trace:

```
04-18 21:01:21.691: W/MediaPlayer(11767): info/warning (973, 0)
04-18 21:01:21.691: V/MediaPlayer(11767): callback application
04-18 21:01:21.691: V/MediaPlayer(11767): back from callback
04-18 21:01:21.701: V/MediaPlayer(11767): message received msg=5, ext1=0, ext2=0
04-18 21:01:21.701: V/MediaPlayer(11767): New video size 0 x 0
04-18 21:01:21.701: V/MediaPlayer(11767): callback application
04-18 21:01:21.701: V/MediaPlayer(11767): back from callback
04-18 21:01:21.701: V/MediaPlayer(11767): message received msg=1, ext1=0, ext2=0
04-18 21:01:21.701: V/MediaPlayer(11767): prepared
04-18 21:01:21.701: V/MediaPlayer(11767): signal application thread
04-18 21:01:21.701: V/MediaPlayer(11767): callback application
04-18 21:01:21.701: V/MediaPlayer(11767): prepare complete - status=0
04-18 21:01:21.701: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(11767): start
04-18 21:01:21.701: V/MediaPlayer(11767): start
04-18 21:01:21.701: V/MediaPlayer(11767): back from callback
04-18 21:01:21.771: I/MediaPlayer(11767): Info (973,0)
04-18 21:01:21.771: I/MediaPlayer(11767): Don't send intent. msg.arg1 = 0, msg.arg2 = 0
```